# Storing the unknown Id of an html tag

Tags: python, html, tags, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I am trying to scrape an html using BeautifulSoup, but I am having problems finding a tag id using Python 3.4. I know what the tag `("tr")` is, but the id is constantly changing and I would like to save the id when it changes. For example:

```
<div class = "thisclass"
  <table id = "thistable">
    <tbody>
      <tr id="what i want">
        <td class = "someinfo">
   <tbody>           
  <table>
<div>
```

I can find the `div` tag and the `table`, and I know the `tr` tag is there, but I want to extract the `text` next to `id`, without knowing what the `text` is going to say.

so far I have this code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.read())
divTag = soup.find_all("table",id ="thistable")
i = 0
for i in divTag:
  trtag = soup.find("tr", id) 
  print(trtag)    
  i = i+1
```

if anyone could help me solve this problem I would appreciate it.

Comment: I would like my output to be the text that is in Id, which in this case is "what i want". The problem is that text is subject to change and I would like my scraper to run automatically.

Comment: Ok, is this the only tr in the table or is it always first?

Comment: There are a few more. Ideally i would like to compare this id value to the other tr tags id value.

Comment: So, you want to get the id attr value for all trs in the table, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`css selector`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
print([element.get('id') for element in soup.select('table#thistable tr[id]'))
```